# Error using Class.forName() to get Class object for a Class

Tags: java

Why does this give an error?

```
public class Getmethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Class t = Class.forName("Getmethods");
        if( t == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class Getmethods

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with `Class.forName()`.

Comment: Still getting same error message.

Comment: give  fully qualified class name. for example `com.test.GetMethods` if `com.test` is your package name.

Comment: But I am in the default package. I am in some directory.

Comment: Are you using command prompt to run you program?

Comment: Your code as given compiles and runs without an exception. I just ran it.

Comment: @khelwood He had a classpath problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you're getting is because your `main` should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

See the [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/):

> In the Java programming language, every application **must contain a
>   main method whose signature is**:
>
> `public static void main(String[] args)`

After your edit, other possible errors:

- Are you sure that you added the location of `.class` file to your classpath?
- Make sure your class name is `Getmethods`
- Clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Only correct answer in `Collection<Answer>`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, even after fixing the signature for main()

Comment: You are right. Classpath is the problem. Thanks Maroun.

Answer (score 0):

I had a classpath problem. If I do

```
javac -cp . Getmethods
```

the code runs fine.